# Job summited with qsub does not write output and enters E status

Tags: qsub

I have a job called test.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#PBS -S /bin/sh
#PBS -V
#PBS -o /my/many/directories/file.log
#PBS -e /my/many/directories/fileerror.log
#PBS -r n
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=1
#PBS -l walltime=01:00:00
#PBS -V
#############################################################################

echo 'hello'

date
sleep 10
date
```

I submit it with qsub test.sh

It counts to 10 seconds, but it doesn't write hello to file.log or anywhere else. If I include a call to another script I need that I programmed (and runs outside the cluster), it just goes to Exiting status after said 10 seconds and plainly ignores the call.

Help, please?

Comment: I changed the job header in order to get an email with more information, and here's what I get: "An error has occurred processing your job, see below. Post job file processing error; job [PBS Job Id] on host [host]

Comment: Are you able to run other jobs?  I have had unexplainable errors related to the jobscript being or not being executable.  Do you have any special reason to use ```/bin/sh -e``` instead of ```/bin/bash```?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ott Toomet for your suggestion! I found the problem elsewhere. The .tschrc file had "bash" written in it. Don't ask me why. I deleted it and now the jobs happily run.